# Stop blink between clock updates

Tags: python

Any way to make this stop blinking after every update of the clocks?
this display a world time zone clock and every time it updates it blinks, i would like to remove that blinking, is there a way to do this?

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import Tk, LabelFrame, Label
import pytz

root = Tk()

def timezones():
    global timezonelbl
    try:
        timezonelbl = LabelFrame(root, text="World Time Zones", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
        timezonelbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=2)

        # list of desired countries
        Country_Zones = ['America/New_York', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Brazil/East',
                         'Chile/EasterIsland', 'Cuba', 'Egypt', 'Europe/Amsterdam',
                         'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Jersey', 'Europe/London',
                         'Europe/Moscow', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Rome', 'Hongkong',
                         'Iceland', 'Indian/Maldives', 'Iran', 'Israel', 'Japan', 'NZ', 'US/Alaska', 'US/Arizona',
                         'US/Central', 'US/East-Indiana', 'Asia/Shanghai',
                         'Europe/Madrid', 'Asia/Urumqi', 'Brazil/Acre', 'Brazil/DeNoronha', 'Brazil/East',
                         'Brazil/West', 'Europe/Amsterdam',
                         'Europe/Dublin', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Vienna', 'Europe/Zurich']

        coo = 0
        roo = 0
        country_time_zones = [
            pytz.timezone(country_time_zone)
            for country_time_zone in Country_Zones
        ]

        for i in range(len(country_time_zones)):
            if coo == 2:
                roo += 1
                coo = 0

            lbl = Label(timezonelbl, text=str(Country_Zones[i] + " : " + datetime.now(country_time_zones[i]).strftime('%d-%m-%y') + " : " + datetime.now(country_time_zones[i]).strftime('%H:%M:%S')), padx=5, pady=5)
            lbl.grid(row=roo, column=coo, sticky='nw', pady=2)
            coo += 1

        timezonelbl.after(1000, timezones)
    except:
        timezonelbl.after(1000, timezones)

timezones()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recreate whole GUI every cycle. The solution is to update only the text values of labels.

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import Tk, LabelFrame, Label
import pytz

root = Tk()

labels = []

timezonelbl = LabelFrame(root, text="World Time Zones", padx=5, pady=5, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
timezonelbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=2)

# list of desired countries
Country_Zones = ['America/New_York', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Australia/Sydney', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Brazil/East',
                    'Chile/EasterIsland', 'Cuba', 'Egypt', 'Europe/Amsterdam',
                    'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Jersey', 'Europe/London',
                    'Europe/Moscow', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Rome', 'Hongkong',
                    'Iceland', 'Indian/Maldives', 'Iran', 'Israel', 'Japan', 'NZ', 'US/Alaska', 'US/Arizona',
                    'US/Central', 'US/East-Indiana', 'Asia/Shanghai',
                    'Europe/Madrid', 'Asia/Urumqi', 'Brazil/Acre', 'Brazil/DeNoronha', 'Brazil/East',
                    'Brazil/West', 'Europe/Amsterdam',
                    'Europe/Dublin', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Vienna', 'Europe/Zurich']

coo = 0
roo = 0
country_time_zones = [
    pytz.timezone(country_time_zone)
    for country_time_zone in Country_Zones
]

for i in range(len(country_time_zones)):
    if coo == 2:
        roo += 1
        coo = 0

    lbl = Label(timezonelbl, padx=5, pady=5)
    lbl.grid(row=roo, column=coo, sticky='nw', pady=2)
    labels.append(lbl)
    coo += 1

def update():
    for label, time_zone, country_zone in zip(labels, country_time_zones, Country_Zones):
        label["text"] = str(country_zone + " : " + datetime.now(time_zone).strftime('%d-%m-%y') + " : " + datetime.now(time_zone).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    timezonelbl.after(1000, update)
    
update()
root.mainloop()
```